# Read string json response from server in swift

Tags: json, swift

i'm facing a problem on how to read the data response from the server and convert it into json format using swift. Before the response was a bit short and it returned the response as JSON but now after adding extra attributes to it it returns a string.

On swift i tried to read the data response returned but i get an error stating that "failed to read data in bad format".

Here's the server response:

```
"{
"status": "VALID_REQUEST",
"error_message": "",
"result": [
    "success":"TRUE",
    "response": {
        "data_type": "OBJECT",
        "data":{"username":"man12@example.com"}
    }
  ]
}"
```

Comment: fix your server instead of trying to parse bad data

Comment: @Cœur I did encode the response using "json_encode" method and the result returned is in string not the actual JSOn format i know

Comment: To be clear: is the issue about the extra quotes at the beginning and the end? Otherwise, please give an example of what format you expect.

Comment: Yes the issue is the extra double quotes, if there's anyway to get rid of them would be much of help atm @Cœur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should aim for a fix server side. Otherwise:

### if you are dealing with Data

You may have to convert it to String for manipulation:

```
// turn the Data to String
var dataString = String(data: serverData, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""

...//manipulate

// turn the String to Data
let fixedData = dataString.data(using: .utf8)
```

### when you have your String

You can drop first and last quotes.

```
dataString = String(dataString.characters.dropFirst().dropLast())
```

Comment: But the last snippet seem not to work to drop the characters so i tried to exclude the condition statement and it worked.

Comment: I've removed the condition, but you will have to remove the code when server get fixed.